# How to automatically detect the version of installed Azure SDK?

Tags: azure-sdk-.net

Is there a simple (documented?) way to detect the actually installed version of Azure SDK in automation script? I am going to define conditional behavior depending on this version.

Currently, I just look into the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\` folder and review its content. But I find it not reliable and not automatable.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the tip that helped me: http://www.robblackwell.org.uk/2011/05/29/determining-the-windows-azure-sdk-version-at-runtime.html

Comment: This link is broken.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 2):

If you used the Windows Platform Installer to install the SDK (which I believe is the standard way to do it now), you can use webpicmd.exe to determine which SDK is installed. For example:

```
webpicmd /List /ListOption:Installed
```

See more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg433092.aspx

Answer (score 2):

For those who are still looking for this, you can do so by using [Azure powershell cmdlets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj156055.aspx).

```
Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName "<service name>" -slot "<Production or Staging>" | Where-Object -Property SdkVersion | select SdkVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK
```

The version will be the folder name contained within this directory.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/mZAELvy.png]